# date validation just works on text not numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4, and this is my model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0,d}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage="The start date is required")]
[Display(Name="Start Date")]
public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
```

When I enter `asdf` in the `start date`, I got the error message `this is not a date` but when I enter `02`, I didn't get an error message. Instead I got a `state` error in the server when I use `modelstate`

I am using `{0,d}` to validation the date.

Comment: Have you tried adding `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`. Also update your `DisplayFormat` annotation to `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0,d}")]` and see if that helps.

Comment: @StinkyTowel it still accept `02`

Comment: @user1721236 yes i tried and i replaied to your answer

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - can you post what your rendered HTML is for **startDate**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0,d}")]
```

to

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
```

Comment: it stills accept just `02`, i made ur editing but it doesn't work with me